# Rails Carrierwave NoMethodError

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave, jcrop

I'm trying to implement Jcrop in my app and keep getting the following error:

```
NoMethodError in PeopleController#update
undefined method `body' for nil:NilClass
```

I'm using Rails 4.0.2, Ruby 2.0.0p0, Bootstrap 2.3.2, Jcrop 0.9.12 , Rmagick 2.13.2

What's strange is that the cropped picture is saved to S3 and shown in the UI if I reload the person's page. But, this error is occurring every time I try to crop a picture.

Here is my People model. I've marked the line with ** that is highlighted in the browser when the error is generated.

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates_presence_of :fname, :lname, :company, :department, :title, :work_phone, :mobile, :office, :address, :city, :state, :zipcode, :country, :suite, :column

    attr_accessor :crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_w, :crop_h

    mount_uploader :photo, PhotoUploader

    after_update :crop_photo

  def crop_photo
    **photo.recreate_versions! if crop_x.present?**
  end
end
```

Here is my PhotoUploader.rb file:

```
# encoding: utf-8

class PhotoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  # Include RMagick or MiniMagick support:
  include CarrierWave::RMagick
  # include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  # storage :file
   storage :fog

   include CarrierWave::MimeTypes
   process :set_content_type

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  # This is a sensible default for uploaders that are meant to be mounted:
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  # Provide a default URL as a default if there hasn't been a file uploaded:
  def default_url
    # For Rails 3.1+ asset pipeline compatibility:
    ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_'))

    # "/images/fallback/" + [version_name, "default.png"].compact.join('_')
  end

  # Process files as they are uploaded:
  # process :scale => [200, 300]
  #
  # def scale(width, height)
  #   # do something
  # end

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:

  version :large do
    process :resize_to_limit => [600, 600]
  end

  version :thumb do
    process :crop
    process :resize_to_limit => [200, 200]
  end

  def crop
    if model.crop_x.present?
      resize_to_limit(600, 600)
      manipulate! do |img|
        x = model.crop_x.to_i
        y = model.crop_y.to_i
        w = model.crop_w.to_i
        h = model.crop_h.to_i
        img.crop!(x, y, w, h)
      end
    end
  end

  after :store, :remove_original_file

  def remove_original_file(p)
    if self.version_name.nil?
      self.file.delete if self.file.exists?
    end
  end

  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  # For images you might use something like this:
  # def extension_white_list
  #   %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  # end

  # Create random filename the filename of the uploaded files:
  def filename
     "#{secure_token(10)}.#{file.extension}" if original_filename.present?
  end

  protected
  def secure_token(length=16)
    var = :"@#{mounted_as}_secure_token"
    model.instance_variable_get(var) or model.instance_variable_set(var, SecureRandom.hex(length/2))
  end
end
```

Here is the Update action in my controller:

```
  def update
    # respond_to do |format|
      if @person.update(person_params)
        if params[:person][:photo].present?
          render :crop
        else
          redirect_to @person, notice: "Successfully updated person."
        end
      #   format.html { redirect_to @person, notice: 'Person was successfully updated.' }
      #   format.json { head :no_content }
      # else
      #   format.html { render action: 'edit' }
      #   format.json { render json: @person.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    # end
  end
```

Here is my form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @person, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal', :multipart => 'true' } do |f| %>


  <div class="upload">
    <!-- <div class="photo"> -->
        <%= image_tag @person.photo.url(:thumb).to_s %> 
    <!-- </div> -->
        <%= f.file_field :photo, label: 'Upload Photo' %>
    </div>

  <%= f.input :ntid, label: 'NTID:', :input_html => { :readonly => true } %>
  <%= f.input :fname, label: 'First Name:' %>
  <%= f.input :mname, label: 'Middle Name:' %>
  <%= f.input :lname, label: 'Last Name:' %>
  <%= f.input :company, label: 'Company:' %>
  <%= f.input :department, label: 'Department:' %>
  <%= f.input :title, label: 'Title:' %>
  <%= f.input :email, label: 'E-Mail:' %>
  <%= f.input :work_phone, label: 'Work Phone:' %>
  <%= f.input :mobile, label: 'Mobile Phone:' %>
  <%= f.input :fax, label: 'FAX:' %>
  <%= f.input :office, label: 'Office:' %>
  <%= f.input :address, label: 'Address:' %>
  <%= f.input :city, label: 'City:' %>
  <%= f.input :state, collection: [ "Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California", "Colorado", "Connecticut", "Delaware", "District of Columbia", "Florida", "Georgia", "Hawaii", "Idaho", "Illinois", "Indiana", "Iowa", "Kansas", "Kentucky", "Louisiana", "Maine", "Maryland", "Massachusetts", "Michigan", "Minnesota", "Mississippi", "Missouri", "Montana", "Nebraska", "Nevada", "New Hampshire", "New Jersey", "New Mexico", "New York", "North Carolina", "North Dakota", "Ohio", "Oklahoma", "Oregon", "Pennsylvania", "Puerto Rico", "Rhode Island", "South Carolina", "South Dakota", "Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", "Vermont", "Virginia", "Washington", "West Virginia", "Wisconsin", "Wyoming" ], label: 'State:' %>
  <%= f.input :zipcode, label: 'Zipcode:' %>
  <%= f.input :country, priority: [ "US" ], collection: [ "Canada", "Ireland", "India", "US"], label: 'Country:' %>
  <%= f.input :suite, label: 'Suite:' %>
  <%= f.input :column, label: 'Column:' %>
  <%= f.input :assistant, label: 'Assistant:' %>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit, :class => 'btn-primary' %>
    <%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")),
                people_path, :class => 'btn' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Here is what I'm seeing in my development.log

```
Started PATCH "/people/3" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-13 14:47:12 -0600
Processing by PeopleController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"et3p2hPLTKvVh7aAkD9OCq8IHJe9kZ52L/WFiNmity0=", "person"=>{"crop_x"=>"200", "crop_y"=>"0", "crop_w"=>"400", "crop_h"=>"400"}, "commit"=>"Crop Photo", "id"=>"3"}
  [1m[36mPerson Load (1.5ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "people".* FROM "people" WHERE "people"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", "3"]]
  [1m[35m (1.3ms)[0m  BEGIN
  [1m[36m (0.2ms)[0m  [1mROLLBACK[0m
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1430ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `body' for nil:NilClass):
  app/models/person.rb:11:in `crop_photo'
  app/controllers/people_controller.rb:49:in `update'
```

Here is my full trace:

```
carrierwave (0.9.0) lib/carrierwave/storage/fog.rb:227:in `read'
carrierwave (0.9.0) lib/carrierwave/uploader/cache.rb:77:in `sanitized_file'
carrierwave (0.9.0) lib/carrierwave/uploader/cache.rb:116:in `cache!'
carrierwave (0.9.0) lib/carrierwave/uploader/versions.rb:225:in `recreate_versions!'
app/models/person.rb:11:in `crop_photo'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:386:in `_run__335866053033251740__update__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:310:in `update_record'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/timestamp.rb:70:in `update_record'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:477:in `create_or_update'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `block in create_or_update'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:383:in `_run__335866053033251740__save__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:302:in `create_or_update'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:106:in `save'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/validations.rb:51:in `save'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:32:in `save'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:270:in `block (2 levels) in save'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:326:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:200:in `transaction'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:209:in `transaction'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:323:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:270:in `block in save'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:281:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:269:in `save'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:230:in `block in update'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:326:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:202:in `block in transaction'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:210:in `within_new_transaction'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:202:in `transaction'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:209:in `transaction'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:323:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:228:in `update'
app/controllers/people_controller.rb:49:in `update'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:413:in `_run__922881453698794513__process_action__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:245:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:44:in `process'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:680:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:241:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:486:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:626:in `call'
activerecord (4.0.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:369:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:373:in `_run__3121532127090690729__call__callbacks'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:80:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:64:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:25:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `tagged'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.0.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
railties (4.0.2) lib/rails/application.rb:97:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
/Users/scottsipiora/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/Users/scottsipiora/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/Users/scottsipiora/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Any ideas on what I can do to fix this problem?

Thanks

Comment: can u show your form?

Comment: Somewhere you're calling the method `body` of an object, and that object is `nil`. Try to find where is it, maybe in the layout or somewhere else in the update view?

Comment: Hi Sergio, I searched everywhere for "body" and only found valid <body> and <tbody> references. When I looked at my development.log (which I've added) I think the problem is caused by some lines I commented out in my controller (which I'm now showing). I commented them out because I'm a bit of a noob and didn't think they were needed and when I removed them the issue I had was fixed. So it seems like it's looking for the "update as HTML' code but I've commented it out. I removed them because when they were there I got a "AbstractController::DoubleRenderError in PeopleController#update"

Comment: Can you show full stack trace

Answer (score 0):

The actual code triggering the exception is in the [Carrierwave repository](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/master/lib/carrierwave/storage/fog.rb#L227).
Backtracking to see [where](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/master/lib/carrierwave/uploader/cache.rb#L77) it is actually called tells that it's trying to cache a file that for some reason does not exist. Next steps for debugging would be to actually ensure that the files you are trying to re-crop exist. Im thinking that because you are doing this in the `after_update`hook, your files might not exist in the state you need them.

Comment: When I comment out that line of my model I'm not getting any errors (that's good). But, the image doesn't get cropped either. Humm...

Comment: I cannot debug your code for you, as I don't have it cannot run it. I can only tell you where you should potentially be looking.

Comment: Hi Tanel, I know, I'm looking. Thanks.